# Condition on tangent lines and section of a line bundle on curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth, complex, projective algebraic curve (not contained in a plane) in $\mathbb P^3$. Suppose that we have found $n$ points $p_1,...p_n$ on $C$ such that the tangent lines to $C \subset \mathbb P^3$ at all those points are not pairwise coplanar. Does this conditions imply that there is no nonzero sections of the line bundle given by $\mathcal O_C(1)(-2p_1-2p_2-....-2p_n)$?

Is the  relation between the condition on tangent lines and vanishing of global sections follows from something obvious? (Till now I couldn't find an explicit argument for this)

Any remark from anyone is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true as long as $n>1$. Consider the short exact sequence $$0\to \mathcal{O}_X(1-\sum 2p_i)\to \mathcal{O}_X(1)\to \bigoplus \mathcal{O}_{X,p_i}/\mathfrak{m}^2\to 0$$ and take global sections. Global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(1-\sum2p_i)$ are exactly global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ vanishing to order two at each $p_i$, which means they have to contain the tangent line at $p_i$. But by assumption on the tangent lines, there cannot be any plane containing all these tangent lines.

In general, if $D$ is a very ample divisor on a curve $X$ and $E$ is another effective divisor, then global sections of $D-E$ correspond to hyperplanes in $|D|$ which vanish on $E$ under the embedding $X\to |D|$ determined by $D$. When $E$ has a point $p$ of multiplicity $m$, "vanishing on $E$" means hyperplanes which intersect $X$ with multiplicity at least $m$ at $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ( especially for pointing out the correspondence part in the last paragraph).